# tiger snack or tiger's snack?

Tags: grammar

I read this phrase in a book:

> Today, you're likely to be a tiger snack.

Is that correct? I mean are not we supposed to write ***tiger's snack*** instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Both are correct.

> A tiger snack

Means "a snack for tigers". It's referring to tigers in *general*.

> A tiger's snack

Means "a snack for a tiger". It's referring to a *specific* tiger, who owns a snack.

---

This is common in English:

> A car door - A door that is found/used on cars.
>   A car's door - A door that belongs to a specific car.
>
> A dog treat - A treat for dogs.
>   A dog's treat - A treat that belongs to a specific dog.
>
> A shark tooth, a shark's tooth. A human skeleton, a human's skeleton.

Comment: @downvoters; care to elaborate what's wrong with the answer? I'm open to improving it, if I know what needs improving.